# NotFoundHttpException Laravel/Lumen

Tags: php, laravel, jwt

I am trying to create a project with multiple authentications of 2 users (`patients` and `doctors`) using Lumen.

Each time I want to run the server, I get the following error:

HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed

This is my `CorsMiddlware`:

```php
class CorsMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        //Intercepts OPTIONS requests
        if ($request->isMethod('OPTIONS')) {
            $response = response('', 200);
        } else {
            // Pass the request to the next middleware
            $response = $next($request);
        }

        // Adds headers to the response
        $response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'HEAD, GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
        $response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', $request->header('Access-Control-Request-Headers'));
        $response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        $response->header('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', 'Location');

        // Sends it
        return $response;
    }
}
```

My `web.php`:

```php
$router->group(['prefix' => 'patient'], function () use ($router) {   
    $router->post('register', 'Patient/PatientAuthController@register');
    $router->post('login', 'Patient/PatientAuthController@login');
    $router->get('view-profile','Patient/PatientAuthController@viewProfile');
    $router->get('logout','Patient/PatientAuthController@logout');
    $router->post('refresh-token','Patient/PatientAuthController@refreshToken');
});
```

My controller :

```
      protected $patient;
    protected $utilityService;


    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware("auth:patient",['except'=>['login','register']]);
        $this->patient = new Patient;
        $this->utilityService = new UtilityService;
    }


    public function register(PatientRegisterRequest $request)
   {
       $password_hash = $this->utilityService->hash_password($request->password);
       $this->patient->createPatient($request,$password_hash);
       $success_message = "registration completed successfully";
    return  $this->utilityService->is200Response($success_message);
   }


    /**
     * Get a JWT via given credentials.
     *
     * @param  Request  $request
     * @return Response
     */
    public function login(LoginRequest $request)
    {
        $credentials = $request->only(['email', 'password']);

        if (! $token = Auth::guard('patient')->attempt($credentials)) {
            $responseMessage = "invalid username or password";
            return $this->utilityService->is422Response($responseMessage);
         }
         

        return $this->respondWithToken($token);
    }


    public function viewProfile()
    {
        return response()->json([
            'success'=>true,
            'patient' => Auth::guard('patient')->patient()
            ]
            , 200);
    }

    
   /**
     * Log the application out (Invalidate the token).
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function logout()
    {
        try {
           
             $this->logUserOut();

        } catch (TokenExpiredException $e) {
            
            $responseMessage = "token has already been invalidated";
            $this->tokenExpirationException($responseMessage);
        } 
    }

    
    public function logUserOut()
    {
        Auth::guard('patient')->logout();
        $responseMessage = "successfully logged out";
      return  $this->utilityService->is200Response($responseMessage);
    }


    public function tokenExpirationException($responseMessage)
    {
        return $this->utilityService->is422Response($responseMessage);
    }

    /**
     * Refresh a token.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function refreshToken()
    {
        try
         {
            return $this->respondWithToken(Auth::guard('patient')->refresh());
        }
         catch (TokenExpiredException $e)
         {
            $responseMessage = "Token has expired and can no longer be refreshed";
            return $this->tokenExpirationException($responseMessage);
        } 
    }
```

i have registred the middlware in app.php , but still it doesnt work

i have also checked the .htaccess file  for RewriteEngine On !

Any help would be appreciated .

Comment: can you share code for your `PatientAuthController`

Comment: i just edited the post , thank you for you reply !

Comment: @Chaker.asm please, do not share images as the images can get down and the post will lose all meanings, copy paste your code instead of sharing images. Also, which URL are you trying to access ?

Comment: ok mate , ill try to , btw i want to access  localhost:8000/patient/register to test it out .

Comment: the only thing I can see from this is you might be sending GET requests and your endpoint excepts POST.